# Prefetch items and return requested item immediately

Tags: python, caching, pyqt5, background-process, prefetch

I need to load a lot of large image data from a network-share for processing (which is not very fast). The images are named following a sequence (e.g. 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, etc.).

In most cases, loading will happen in this sequence (loading n+1.png after n.png). I would like to have n+1.png in memory before the actual request.

I would like to keep a cache (as well), such that going 1 image back does not require disk access.

I envision something like this:

1. Request image with index n
2. Check if n.png is in cache, if the image is not in cache:
   a. load the image from disk
   b. put the image in cache
3. Perform steps 1&2 for image with index n+1
4. Do **not** wait for step 3 to finish, but take the image from cache and return that image

Nice to have feature: clean the cache in the backgound such that it only contains the last requested 10 items, or that it removes the first requested items until it contains a max. of 10 items (I can imagine the latter option is easier to implement while being good enough for my case).

I am using Python 3.5. I am using PyQt5, but I prefer the function to not rely on PyQt5 functionality (but if this makes the implementation much more clean/easy/readable I will use it).

Comment: Please enlighten me; why the -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer (assuming you're not using coroutines or the like, which you probably aren't given that you're using PyQt5) is to spawn a daemon background thread to load image n+1 into the cache. Like this:

```
def load(self, n):
    with self._cache_lock:
        try:
            return self._cache[n]
        except KeyError:
            self._cache[n] = self._load_image(n)
            return self._cache[n]
def process_image(self, n):
    img = self.load(n)
    threading.Thread(target=partial(self.load, n+1), daemon=True).start()
    self.step1(img)
    self.step2(img)
```

The problem with this design is that you're holding a lock around the entire `_load` operation. If `step1` and `step2` take significantly longer than `_load_image`, it may be cheaper to avoid that lock by allowing rare duplicate work:

```
def cacheget(self, n):
    with self._cache_lock:
        return self._cache.get(n)
def preload(self, n):
    img = self._load_image(n)
    with self._cache_lock:
        self._cache[n] = img
    return img
def process_image(self, n):
    img = self.cacheget(n)
    if img is None:
        img = self.preload(n)
    threading.Thread(target=partial(self.preload, n+1), daemon=True).start()
    self.step1(img)
    self.step2(img)
```

If you're expecting to do lots of processing in parallel, you may want to use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to queue up all of your preloads, instead of a daemon thread for each one.

If you want to clean old cache values, see [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) and [its implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/functools.py#L399). There are a lot of tuning decisions to make (like: do you actually want background cache garbage collection, or can you just push the oldest item out whenever you add a 10th item the way `lru_cache` does?), but none of the options are particularly hard to build once you decide what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have developped a [library](https://github.com/nlgranger/SeqTools) which I believe does exactly that:

```py
files = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png']
images = seqtools.smap(load_img, files)  # (on-demand) image loading
images = seqtools.prefetch(images, max_buffered=10, method='thread')  # prefetching
images = seqtools.add_cache(images, cache_size=10)  # lru cache
image[0]
images[1]
```

The way prefetching works is to enqueue the evaluation of items that come right after the last requested one.

Thread/process and memory cleanup is automatically handled.

Note that the above code has 20 images in memory: 10 for the prefetching buffer and 10 for the recently requested items.

Finally, you might want to switch between the threading and multiprocessing backends depending on what your loading function does.